# Java Sound Demo - Problem

Tags: java, audio

I have downloaded and run the [Java sound demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) available on http://java.sun.com/. When I run the capture/playback example I can record and playback my voice. But after I save the voice in to a wav file, I can't playback it and get an error as,

> Unable to reset the stream
>   java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported

Can you tell me why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this (very old) bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4948663):

> This bug is caused primarily by a
> recent change in PushBackInputStream:
> AudioInputStream used
> PushBackInputStream internally in
> order to cope with irregular frame
> size reads of the underlying input
> stream.

It looks like the problem is that AudioInputStream does not support `reset()`, which is causing this problem. The suggested work-around is to use java 1.4.1 to run the demo. Of course, I expect that this is changed in the main API, so when you develop this yourself, you should have no problem doing it with Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Banang. I am running this on Java 6, but I still get the problem.

Comment: @gishu Hum, maybe I wasn't very clear. You running this on 1.6 should be exactly why this problem occurrs. There was a change in the AudioInputStream after 1.4.1 that made this sample break. If you run the sample on an older version of Java it will work, because it is built using a very old version. However, the api is updated, so you will be able to develop using Java 1.6.

Comment: @gishu no worries, I was probably not being clear enough. Good luck with your sound development!